# How to Display Descriptive List Group in .NET core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, bootstrap-4

[image: here is the generated HTML]I wish to create a UI like [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/list-group/#javascript-behavior) using .NET core MVC framework.

what should my view be like?

i tired looping through each data model and embedding razor code into the same bootstrap tempate but i'm not getting anywhere near the desired functionality.

```
<div class="container h-100 w-100">
  <div class="row w-100 ml-0 mr-0 mt-0 mb-0">


    <div class="col-3">
         <div class="list-group" id="list-tab" role="tablist">
            @{
                foreach(var user in Model)
                {
                    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-@user.FirstName-list" data-toggle="list" href="#@user.FirstName" aria-controls="@user.FirstName" role="tab">
                             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => user.FirstName)
                    </a>
                }
            }
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-9">
         <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
            @{
                foreach(var user in Model)
                {

                   <div class="tab-pane fade show " id="list-@user.FirstName" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-@user.FirstName-list">
                      <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => user.FirstName)</p>
                   </div>

                }
            }
        </div>
    </div>  
  </div> 
 </div>
```

The first part of the list group is getting displayed but when i try clicking on it, i dont get to see the description

Comment: Can you post your generated HTML ?

Comment: Here is the generated HTML @N

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are appending "list-" to id of your `.tab-pane`, while the href for list item does not have that prefix.

Second, you can make the first active selection via JavaScript. Avoid putting `fade show` in your razor code, or put the condition in loop such that it should add it to only first element.

HTML :

```
            <div class="col-3">
                <div class="list-group" id="list-tab" role="tablist">

                    @foreach (var user in Model)
                    {
                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-@user.FirstName-list" data-toggle="list" href="#@user.FirstName" aria-controls="@user.FirstName" role="tab">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => user.FirstName)
                        </a>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-9">
                <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">

                    @foreach (var user in Model)
                    {
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="@user.FirstName" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-@user.FirstName-list">
                            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => user.FirstName)</p>
                        </div>

                    }

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS :

```
<script>
    $(".tab-pane").first().addClass("fade show active");
    $(".list-group-item").first().addClass("active");
</script>
```